# Will I see you before the evening/night?

Tags: questions

Is it right to say that to the person I live with or there are other expressions in this case?

> Will I see you before the evening?

> Will I see you before the night?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this kind of casual contact with a housemate/partner you'd do better just to speak, since nobody is going to be assessing your English, and if they don't understand you, they can always ask.

What you say is very understandable.  I'd probably use "this evening" and "tonight" rather than "the evening".